# Using Kinematic Equations of Motion to find Velocity in Spring-Block System

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, work, spring

Suppose a block of mass, *m* is connected to a spring of force constant, *k*. The block is moved on a frictionless surface through distance, *b* with the help of a **uniform external force**, *F* so that the spring gets stretched.
What will be the velocity of the block when it completes the distance, *b*?

**Known Quantities:-**
Mass - *m*
Force Constant - *k*
Distance - *b*
Force - *F*

**Unknown Quantity:** Velocity - *v*

*Note: The mass of the spring and the velocity with which it is moved with the block is considered negligible in both the following methods*.

---

#### Method 1:-

When the block is moved(consequently, the spring will stretch), the **work done by the external force** will **get stored as Potential Energy(PE) in the spring** and also, **will appear as Kinetic Energy(KE) of the block**.

Initally, the block is at rest, so $KE_i=0$ and at equilibrium position, so $PE_i=0$

$W=\vec{F}\cdot \vec{b} = F b cos0 $
$W=Fb$

$W= \Delta PE(Spring) + \Delta KE(Block)$
$W= (PE_f - PE_i) + (KE_f - KE_i)$

$Fb= \frac{1}{2}kb^2 + \frac{1}{2}mv^2$

$v^2= \frac{2Fb-kb^2}{m}$

$v=\sqrt{\frac{b(2F-kb)}{m}}$

*My book solved the problem with this method.

But I tried a different method where I used Newton's equations of motion.*

---

#### Method 2:-

As the Force is **uniform**, so the **acceleration, a** produced in the block will also be **uniform**. So, we can apply *Newton's Equations Of Motion*.

$F=ma$

$a=\frac{F}{m}$

Initially, the block was at rest, so intital velocity, $u=o$.

Applying 3rd equation of motion,

$v^2=u^2+2as$

$v=\sqrt{2ab}$

---

Now, I just want to make sure that is the method correct or not.
If it's correct then, both the methods 1 and 2 should give same velocity.

But, that's the real problem that the values of velocity from method 1 and method 2 are not matching up.

Please, figure me out.

Comment: With simple harmonic motion, $a \propto -x$ which means that the acceleration is not constant. Just because there is a constant force F on the block doesn't mean the net force will be constant.

Comment: The **net** force acting on the block **is not** constant, because the spring provides a restorative force $F=kx$ that opposes the external (constant) force.

Comment: Ok, I don't how this question is off-topic. I didn't put the tag homework-and-excercises when I posted this question. I ask about whether I can solve it using Equations of Motion or not(which I think comes under the Physics domain) and though I have shown 2 different methods of solving it, the reason for putting it on hold is "show some effort" and "ask about a specific physics concept". Can anyone explain this???

Answer (score 3):

You got stuck with the second method because you're using an incorrect Newton's Equation of Motion. The correct  one is (the object travels on the $x$ axis), where $F$ is a constant force acting on the block:

$$ma=F-kx$$
$$m\ddot{x}+kx-F=0$$

But it's very clear that the method of conservation of energy is far simpler. Have a look at this derivation.

Substitute:

$$kx-F=X$$
So:
$$k\dot{x}=\dot{X}$$
$$k\ddot{x}=\ddot{X}\implies \ddot{x}=\frac1k\ddot{X}$$
$$\frac{m}{k}\ddot{X}+X=0$$
$$\ddot{X}+\frac kmX=0$$
So the differential equation is  now *homogeneous*:

Set:

$$\frac km=\omega^2$$

$$\ddot{X}+\omega^2 X=0$$
This classic *second order differential equation* solves to:

$$X(t)=A\cos(\omega t+\phi)$$
Where $A$ and $\phi$ are constants (amplitude and phase angle, resp.) that we determine from the *initial conditions*. So:

Assume at $t=0$, $x=0 \implies X(0)=-F$

$$-F=A\cos\phi$$
Assume at $t=0, \dot{x}=0 \implies \dot{X}(0)=0$.

$$\dot{X}=-A\omega\sin(\omega t+\phi)$$
$$\dot{X}(0)=-A\omega\sin\phi=0\implies \phi=0$$
$$A=-F$$
$$X(t)=-F\cos\omega t=kx(t)-F$$
$$\boxed{x(t)=\frac Fk(1-\cos\omega t)}$$
So this is the equation of motion.
And this is the expression for velocity in time:
$$\boxed{\dot{x}=\frac Fk \omega \sin \omega t}$$

Use these to find the time needed to travel the distance $b$, then use that time, say $t_b$, to determine $\dot{x}(t_b)$ with the velocity expression.

So that's quite a kerfuffle, compared to the conservation method, which explains why your textbook recommends it. **The object lesson is that if you're not tasked to find the exact trajectory of the object(s), solve this kind of problem with conservation, preferably.**