# Equation of simple harmonic motion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

Would

$$ \frac{{\rm d}^2 x}{{\rm d}t^2} + \omega^2 x = {\rm (constant)}$$ be an SHM?

My instinct is no, as acceleration would not be zero at x = 0, but a solution in my book uses this equation to find angular frequency for an SHM.

Comment: Let $x = y+\frac{k}{\omega^2}$...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say:
$$\ddot{x}+\omega^2 x=C$$
$$\ddot{x}+\omega^2 x-C=0$$

Substitute:

$$u=\omega^2 x-C$$
$$\dot{u}=\omega^2\dot{x}$$
$$\ddot{u}=\omega^2\ddot{x}\implies \ddot{x}=\frac{1}{\omega^2}\ddot{u}$$
$$\implies \frac{1}{\omega^2}\ddot{u}+u=0$$
Or:

$$\ddot{u}+\omega^2 u=0$$

Which is the ODE for an SHM.

Solve, apply boundary conditions and backsubstitute $u$.

[Here's a practical example, fully worked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/369896/using-kinematic-equations-of-motion-to-find-velocity-in-spring-block-system/369910#369910).

> My instinct is no, as acceleration would not be zero at $x = 0$

That's not a requirement of an SHM, see my worked example.

Comment: I still don't understand why acceleration doesn't have to be zero at the mean position.  Mean position implies stable equilibrium which implies that the net force at that point is zero.

Comment: @user165756: did you check my worked example (link)? As $ma=F-kx$, at $x=0$, clearly $a\neq 0$. Mean position would be stable equilibrium if NO oscillation took place at all.

Comment: Ah... sorry, I didn't understand the example before. Thank you.